# xcode Build and Analyze related questions

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, build

I was watching the videos from WWDC 2010 and have now started to dig in to the functionality of the Build and Analyze tool in xcode 3.2. It's a great tool that will highlight coding mistakes (specially for a newcomer like me!) even if they may not have an impact during runtime.

But there is one thing I would need some help to understand.

When I push a new view controller with this code:

```
SettingsViewController *nextController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil];

My_AppAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[delegate.myNavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

The analyzer tells me there is a potential memory leak. I can understand that in a way, as I allocate the NextController but never release it. But if I try to release it, my app crashes.

I dont get any leaks when analyzing with Instruments on the simulator and physical device.

Would Apple stop this app or would it go through their testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitted the App to Apple and it passed.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably not be rejected for leaks unless they lead to an unhandled memory warning and crash.  That said, the specific problem you mention can be fixed using [`autorelease`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW5).

```
SettingsViewController *nextController = [[[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

The navigation controller should retain the view controller for its lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. I tested it and it works fine in the build and analyze and the first time I push the controller. The second time I do it the app crashes. How is it with autorelease and iOS? From what I understand there is no garbage collection in iOS, but in some places they still refer to autorelease...

Comment: I strongly recommend you read Apple's memory management programming guide.  I don't have a link handy, but it will answer more questions than any comment here.